# Why do SQL injection not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max);
set @a ='''a'' OR Name like ''%a'';';

--Why the below query not working
Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name = @a

-- The query below was executed to make sure that the query above 
   being constructed properly
print 'SQL: Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name ='+ @a
--SQL: Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name ='a' OR Name like '%a';
```

Correct me if im wrong, SQL injection wont work in Stored Procedure is due to some precompiled factor but the above scenario was tested in query statement instead of Stored Procedure. Why still not working?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. You don't show the query not working, you show yourself printing it with a prefix 'SQL: '. If you want to execute the command, then compose the whole thing into a string and execute it with `sp_executesql`.

Comment: PRINT does not execute any sql commands.

Comment: _SQL Injection_ usually means attempting to inject malicious code into SQL. It looks like what you're actually trying to do is _dynamic sql_, where you concoct a string and execute it with `exec` or `sp_execute_sql`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: My intention was to understand SQL injection but guess that I've made the wrong assumption that `@a` converted the whole query into a string and expected to executed successfully. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Injection occurs when data is confused for and interpreted as code.

This does not happen in your scenario since parameter or variable *values* are not directly interpreted as code - they're only at risk of being interpreted as code if you construct new code by combining strings and these parameter/variable values and then pass the entire constructed string to the system and ask it to interpret the entire string as code - via `exec`, `sp_executesql` or other such means.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you think that *would* work. `@a` is a `varchar` variable, so `Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name = @a` finds rows where `Name` is equal to the value of that variable.

If you want SQL-Server to take the value of `@a` and insert it into the query *as code*, then you need to use `sp_executesql` (analogous to `eval` in languages like Bash and Python and JavaScript):

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 'Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name = ' + @a
```

Answer (score 0):

Look there is no name ending with 'a'. Try like

```
Select TOP 10 * FROM Member where Name ='a' OR Name like '%a%'
```

**Updated**

Microsoft handle SQL injection for SQL parameters.

Comment: Nope, I've tested to execute the printed statement, it returned results. In my table there are a lot of member with name ended with A

Comment: Look Microsoft well handle in SQL parameter for injection like C# SQL Parameters.